# Unable to add authorization to swagger api document in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, nswag

I have a asp.net core 6 project setup for multiple api versioning. However, when I open the nswager api document. The Authorize button on the right side does not display at all. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Below is my snippet code:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerTest(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string apiName)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(1, 0);
                opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
                opt.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
                                                                new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"),
                                                                new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
            })
            .AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
            {
                setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            })
            .AddSwaggerGen(option =>
            {
                option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Please enter a valid token",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });

                option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id="Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        new string[]{}
                    }
                });

                option.EnableAnnotations();
                option.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);


                var provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{apiName}.xml");

                    if (File.Exists(xmlPath))
                    {
                        option.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                    }
                }
            })
            .AddSwaggerDocuments(apiName);

            return serviceCollection;
        }

        private static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerDocuments(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string swaggerApiName)
        {
            var provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                serviceCollection.AddSwaggerDocument(config =>
                {
                    config.DocumentName = description.GroupName.ToLower();

                    config.PostProcess = document =>
                    {

                        document.Info.Version = description.GroupName.ToLower();
                        document.Info.Title = swaggerApiName;
                        document.Info.Description = description.IsDeprecated
                            ? "This Api version has been depreciated"
                            : "A versioned TTC Fas Rest API";
                    };

                    config.ApiGroupNames = new[] { description.GroupName.ToLower() };
                });
            }

            return serviceCollection;
        }
```

So in my Progarm.cs. I would have something like this:

```
\\ Something ...
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerTest("test");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
{
    authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
    jwtOptions.SaveToken = true;
    jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "Test",
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:7117",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@2410"))
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseOpenApi();
    app.UseSwaggerUi3(config => config.DocExpansion = "list");
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My v1 controller:

```
[ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching", "v1"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

v2 controller:

```
[ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching", "v2"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I also have the login controller in both v1 and v2.

===========================================================

I have found a solution for myself. I am not using `UseOpenApi` and
`UseSwaggerUi3` from `Nswag.AspnetCore` package anymore, so I decided to remove this package and use the `UseSwagger` and `UseSwaggerUI` from
`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI`

Everything inside the `AddSwaggerTest` function and controllers are the same.
Here is how I make it work:

```
\\ something is running
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerTest("test");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
{
    authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
    jwtOptions.SaveToken = true;
    jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "Test",
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:7117",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@2410"))
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

var apiVersionDescriptionProvider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
          foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
          {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                        description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
          }
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Hi Hoang Minh, I saw you have updated this post, could you summarize it as answer below and accept it, not updated in the origin post. Other forum users who facing the same issue, will find the solution quickly. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for myself. I am not using `UseOpenApi` and `UseSwaggerUi3` from `Nswag.AspnetCore` package anymore, so I decided to remove this package and use the `UseSwagger` and `UseSwaggerUI` from `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI`

Everything inside the `AddSwaggerTest` function and controllers are the same. Here is how I make it work:

```
// something is running
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerTest("test");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
{
    authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
    jwtOptions.SaveToken = true;
    jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "Test",
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:7117",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@2410"))
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

var apiVersionDescriptionProvider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
          foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
          {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                        description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
          }
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Hope it helps someone :)